# Android Relative Layout alignParentRight and alignParentEnd

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to figure out the difference between the layout params for relative layout, specifically alignParentRight and alignParentEnd (also alignParentLeft and alignParentStart). Reading the reference doesn't help much, I figured the end of a parent was always its right. Is there any difference to this? Is one depreciated now?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I figured the end of a parent was always its right

Only for left-to-right (LTR) languages. For right-to-left (RTL) languages (e.g., Hebrew, Arabic), end is left and start is right. If you use `end` and `start` attributes, your layout will mirror when it is run on a device set to an RTL locale. If you use `left` and `right`, it will not mirror.

Answer (score 3):

Let me add 1 more point beside @CommonsWare's answer. Please be aware that `alignStart, alignEnd` and `alignParentEnd, alignParentStart` were added in API Level 17, so that you cannot use those attributes before 17.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#layout_alignParentEnd

```
╔═══════════════════════════════════╦═══════════════════════╗
║ API Level 1                       ║ API Level 17          ║
╠═══════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╣
║ alignBaseLine                     ║ align(Start/End)      ║
║ alignWithParentIfMissing          ║ alignParent(Start/End)║
║ align(Top/Bottom/Left/Right)      ║                       ║
║ alignParent(Top/Bottom/Left/Right)║                       ║
╚═══════════════════════════════════╩═══════════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

`alignParentEnd` and `alignParentStart` are used in RTL (right-to-left) layouts in countries where this is a historical norm. In this case "end" actually becomes "left" instead of "right". If you provide all your views with these attributes, your layout will look like horizontally flipped in RTL layouts, which is more convenient for users in these countries.