# Textview next to an ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to have a TextView with an ImageView directly to its right. Right now the image partially overlaps the far right of the text, so if the text inputted is long, then the image is "over" the text. I have an ellipse setting on the text but I need the TextView to "stop" right at the left border of the ImageView.

TextView layout settings:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
```

ImageView layout settings:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
```

Comment: look into drawableX attributes, like `drawableRight` for TextView

Comment: @zgc7009 I did see that, but I need the image to be clickable, which is why I have it as its own ImageView (it's a delete X icon)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/iv"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        .... />

    <!-- background == @null if you don't want default button background -->
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@id/iv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@null"  
        .... />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT**

See the comments in regards to why this works and the posted question doesn't. Also take a look at

[Android Relative Layout alignParentRight and alignParentEnd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29583307/android-relative-layout-alignparentright-and-alignparentend)

for a reference to `end/right` and `start/left` attributes.

Comment: `toLeftOf` was the thing I had been missing! I had tried `toRightof` on the ImageButton but that hadn't worked, so I didn't bother trying the other way. Why does `toLeftOf` on the TextView work but not doing `toRightOf` on the ImageView?

Comment: Because if the TextView takes up the whole width of the screen, then toRightOf will push the ImageView off of to the right of the screen. Doing toLeftOf with parent alignment makes it so that the ImageView is drawn to the right side of the parent, and the TextView is drawn to the left of that. I used to hate figuring out XML views, it is amazing what you can do once you get to know it more.

Comment: There are so many alignment options that I frankly don't understand how it all works together. Practice makes perfect I suppose. Thanks!